# Exception when attempting to run code. String Index out of range

Tags: java

Whenever I try to run the code, it gives me an error after I input how many tickets I would like to buy. This is for a lottery program. Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lottery {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //local data
    String guess;
    int numTickets;
    int counter;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //output
    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like to buy?");
    numTickets = in.nextInt();
    for (counter = 0; counter < numTickets; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");
        guess = in.nextLine();
        int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        String randNumb;
        randNumb = Integer.toString(randNum);
        char ch1 = randNumb.charAt(0);
        char ch2 = randNumb.charAt(1);
        char ch3 = randNumb.charAt(2);

        if (ch1 == guess.charAt(0) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1) && ch3 == guess.charAt(2)) {
            System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
            System.out.print("Congratulations, both pairs matched. /n");
        } else if (ch3 == guess.charAt(2) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1)) {
            System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
            System.out.print("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
        } else if (ch1 == guess.charAt(0) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1)) {
            System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
            System.out.print("Congratulations, the first pair matched.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("The Correct Number: " + randNumb);
        }
        System.out.println("\t Sorry, no matches,  You only had");
        System.out.println("\t one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");

       }
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread \"main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0  at
>   java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)  at
>   lottery.Lottery.main(Lottery.java:32)
>   C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1

This is the exception error displayed when I try to run the program.
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: better use String.valueOf(); instead of Integer.toString(); (had several problems with it). also there is a problem with nextLine and netxInt. google for it

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Note that `Math.random() * 1000` will give a value between 0 and 1000, it may be a value with less than three digits .

Comment: I have made changes but the code still won't execute beyond the same point.

Comment: It says I may have an error on line 33 which is where the if statement begins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the behaviour of `nextInt` method of the `Scanner`. In addition, your code has other errors as well.

The `nextInt` method only reads the next integer and nothing else. This means that the new line character (\n or \r or \r\n depending on the OS) is not read. This is fine until you call `nextLine`. `nextLine` reads every character until it encounters a new line character. So `nextLine` sees this unread new line character and stops reading any further and it returns an empty string, which is then put into your `guess` variable. When you try to access the first character of `guess` using `charAt(0)`, it crashes because `guess` does not have any characters.

I suggest you use `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())` to read an integer from the user.

I've fixed the code for you:

```
String guess;
int numTickets;
int counter;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//output
System.out.println("How many tickets would you like to buy?");
numTickets = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
Random rand = new Random();
for (counter = 0; counter < numTickets; counter++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");
    guess = in.nextLine();
    int randNum = rand.nextInt(1000); 
    String randNumb = String.format("%03d", randNum);
    char ch1 = randNumb.charAt(0);
    char ch2 = randNumb.charAt(1);
    char ch3 = randNumb.charAt(2);

    if (ch1 == guess.charAt(0) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1) && ch3 == guess.charAt(2)) {
        System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
        System.out.print("Congratulations, both pairs matched. /n");
    } else if (ch3 == guess.charAt(2) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1)) {
        System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
        System.out.print("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
    } else if (ch1 == guess.charAt(0) && ch2 == guess.charAt(1)) {
        System.out.print("Winner: " + randNumb);
        System.out.print("Congratulations, the first pair matched.");
    } else {
        System.out.print("The Correct Number: " + randNumb);
    }
    System.out.println("\t Sorry, no matches,  You only had");
    System.out.println("\t one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");

}
```

As you can see, I made other improvements. Firstly, `Math.random() * 1000` can return non three digit numbers so I changed it so that it uses a `Random` object. Using `rand.nextInt(900) + 100` only generates three digit numbers.

Secondly, I used `String.valueOf(randNum)` as XtremeBaumer has said in the comments.

Comment: There is no detectable difference between `String.valueOf` and `Integer.toString`. In fact, one just calls the other.

Comment: Also, you've changed the spec. Now ch1 is always 9, never random. You should instead use `int randNum = rand.nextInt(1000); String randNumb = String.format("%03d", randNum);`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou ch1 is not always 9. I tested it and got 636, 408, 886!

Comment: Sorry I misread the code, but still ch1 is now only between 1 and 9 instead of 0 to 9. So it doesn't vary randomly over the same range as originally intended.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou How do you know what the "original intention" was? The OP might want a number between 100 and 999 but ended up writing `Math.random() * 1000`. Let's see how the OP responds.

Comment: The number that I want to receive from the random class is from 001 - 999

Comment: @Sweeper The program is working swiftly. Thanks to all that help me fix my problem!

Comment: @Ben If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!